# Replace a value found in a Df with a value found in a Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am having troubles writing an operation that replaces values found in a df with values that are found in a dictionary. Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

d=[['English','Alabama','bob','smith']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=["lang",'state','first','last'])
filename='temp'

error_dict={}
error_dict[filename]={}

replace_dict={"state":{"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"},"lang":{"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}}
    
def replace(df, error_dict,colname):
#replace the values found the in df with the value that in the replace_dict
   return df, error_dict

parsing_map={
    "lang": [replace],
    "state":[replace]
    }

for i in parsing_map.keys():
    for j in parsing_map[i]:
        df, error_dict = j(df, error_dict, i)
```

I am trying to run some operation in the 'replace' function that will replace the values found in df columns 'lang' and 'state' with their abbreviated value from the dictionary 'replace_dict'. It makes it a bit more confusing since, instead of trying to reference the column name, you just use `colname`.

I have tried to do something like:

```
def replace(df, error_dict,colname):
    for colname, value in replace_dict.items():
        df[colname] = df[colname].replace(value)
        return df, error_dict
```

this only replaces the state column value and not for the state and lang. **I want it to be in a function** i know its not necessary for this exact application but the end result it is nicer.

The desired output is:

```
d = [['ENG','AL','bob','smith']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=["lang",'state','first','last'])
```

How would I create an operation to replace the values in the df with the values in the dictionary using the replace function and 'colname' to reference the name of the column aka "lang" and "state"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the dict and replace each column one at a time:

```
for colname, value in replace_dict.items():
    df[colname] = df[colname].map(value)
```

EDIT full answer:

```
import pandas as pd

d=[['English','Alabama','bob','smith']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=["lang",'state','first','last'])

replace_dict={"state":{"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"},"lang":{"English":"ENG", "French":"FR"}}

for colname, value in replace_dict.items():
    df[colname] = df[colname].map(value)
```

Comment: im not getting errors but it is not overwriting the values in the df. So English is not becoming ENG

Comment: ` .replace` works for state but not lang @jprebys

Comment: What is `.replace`?

Comment: i updated the question to show where i put replace at.

Comment: You don't need a function, check out my updated answer

Comment: I want to use a function paired w the parsing map so I don’t have to reference the column name directly but the parsing map does that for me. is there a way to loop through it for both states and lang instead of just one at a time?  @jprebys

Comment: You don't have to reference the column names directly this way though, right?

Comment: correct by using 'colname' as the reference to the df column name its avoids having to directly reference the column. this is because when calling the function using `for i in parsing_map.keys():` "i" is getting the column name from the key in the dictionary `parsing_map` @jprebys

Comment: In my example you are also referencing the column name with `colname`, not naming it directly